# Express - Finding subdomain(s)

Tags: express

I have an Express API that's being called from a VueJS app. The app is located at a domain similar to dev.example.com. Part of my API call checks for subdomains using the built in req.subdomains. In this case it should return an array containing "dev", however, it's returning an empty array. Both the VueJS app and Express API are running on an AWS EC2 instance.

**EC2 Nginx File**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  #Vue App & Frontend Files
  location / {
    root /var/www/frontend-app/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  #Node API Reverse Proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host; //Fix: Passes down the requesting host information
  }
}
```

**Frontend API Call**

```
submit() {
  axios.post('/api/users/login', {
    email:'test@example.com', 
    password: 'password'
  })
}
```

**Express API Sample Route**

```
router.post('/users/login', async(req, res) => {
  *Login code omitted*
  res.send(req.subdomains); //Returns [], expected result ['dev']
})
```

I haven't been able to find any solution and was hoping someone would have an idea. Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code that you are using. It will help the community debug your issue. At the moment, there is too little information for us to give a good answer.

Comment: @will-yama, thanks for your reply! Just added some of my code. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: what does `req.hostname` returns? @MartinKT

Comment: @Naresh req.hostname returns "localhost"

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by modifying the nginx config. See modified code above.